# Why jetifier using only 4 worker?

Tags: ios, macos, processor, android-jetifier

When I run react-native app on mini-mac, i see that jetifier only uses 4 workers, while in my windows machine and my colleagues mac machines it uses 8 or 12 workers.
does anyone knows how to improve this? How can i use 12 workers in my mini-mac?

here are some details:
VSCode shows: jetifier found 1400 files to forward-jetify. using 4 worker
macOS Big Sur Version 11.2.3
Processor 3.6GHz Quad-Core Intel Core i3